# Is there a drag close option for mmenu?

Tags: draggable, drag, hammer.js, mmenu

I have mmenu setup with dragOpen, but how do I set it up to drag close?  I don't see this as an option anywhere...  but it seems like an obvious function.

Answer (score 0):

When you click outside the menu (into the page), the menu closes by default, so that such a function is unneeded...